# I was sent a wordpress site to host and I believe it's incomplete

Tags: wordpress

So I was given a zip of a website someone wants me to host, and I had zero prior details about how the site was made. When I opened the archive up all it contained was a wp-content folder, .DS_Store and a sql file. I put up a wordpress lightsail instance on AWS to FTP in and take a look at the file/folder structure, and it seems like they forgot to include files for this site.

I’m not familiar with wordpress site development as I do development with react/node/angular/spring boot/etc. Am I correct in my suspicions that I don’t have all the files to simply reupload this wordpress site?

Comment: You're correct. Take a look at this article to see what else you need in there: https://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/beginners-guide-to-wordpress-file-and-directory-structure/

Comment: @HenryVisotski Although most of those other files are part WP "core" - which you can get from installing WP (but which version?). `wp-content` contains everything unique to the actual website. Except possibly `wp-config.php` in the document root that contains DB connection information etc - but maybe you can get that information from elsewhere?

Comment: To clarify DocRoot, you'll need to modify wp-config.php to connect/point to your local instance of the database.

Comment: @DocRoot I think others clarified at this point, but I'll share the workflows I used. Basically I'd get the whole installation, folders and files and all. Upload that to staging, then update WP version and plugins. Make any fixes, push that live. Download the latest version to store locally as backup.

Comment: @HenryVisotski Hhhm, not sure that they have. One answer says no extra files are required, the other suggests some manual updates for `wp-config.php` only. Maybe you should share your _workflow_ as an answer?

Comment: @DocRoot Appreciate the encouragement - glad you found it useful. I'm not posting the workflow in the answers because it's a way to circumvent the whole problem, but only when the complete backup is available. It doesn't resolve the OP's specific issue. I'll let it humbly hang out here. :)

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is to make a clean install of WordPress on your server.

`wp-config.php` file will be generated with your server info in the install step.

Then via FTP upload the wp-content directory to replace the newly created one (it shall contain the website theme and medias).

In PhpMyAdmin or via wp-cli update the new WordPress database with the one in the sql file you received.

Comment: What about `wp-config.php`?

Comment: updated my answer, you don't need the file because it essentially contains the infos to connect to the database. The one on the previous server wouldn't help you as I suppose database credentials aren't the same on the new server.

Answer (score 1):

so you only have wp-content folder right?

what you need to do is goto this link : https://wordpress.org/latest.zip

download wordpress zip file copy all files from zip except - wp-content folder

and paste it in your domain root with your wp-content folder in  ,,/public_html/

after that edit wp-config.php file

and goto line 23 and edit these with your database credential thats it

```
define( 'DB_NAME', 'database_name_here' );

/** MySQL database username */
define( 'DB_USER', 'username_here' );

/** MySQL database password */
define( 'DB_PASSWORD', 'password_here' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You are likely missing the (doc root)/wp-config.php file.  This contains information needed to connect to the database e.g. host, db name, user name and password.

A standard layout looks something like this

```
<?php
 /**
 
 /* MySQL settings */
define( 'DB_NAME',     'database_name_here' );
define( 'DB_USER',     'username_here' );
define( 'DB_PASSWORD', 'password_here' );
define( 'DB_HOST',     'localhost' );
define( 'DB_CHARSET',  'utf8mb4' );


/* MySQL database table prefix. */
$table_prefix = 'wp_';

 
 /* Authentication Unique Keys and Salts. */
 /* https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/ */
 define( 'AUTH_KEY',         'put your unique phrase here' );
 define( 'SECURE_AUTH_KEY',  'put your unique phrase here' );
 define( 'LOGGED_IN_KEY',    'put your unique phrase here' );
 define( 'NONCE_KEY',        'put your unique phrase here' );
 define( 'AUTH_SALT',        'put your unique phrase here' );
 define( 'SECURE_AUTH_SALT', 'put your unique phrase here' );
 define( 'LOGGED_IN_SALT',   'put your unique phrase here' );
 define( 'NONCE_SALT',       'put your unique phrase here' );  


 /* Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
 if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
    define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');

 /* Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
 require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
```

You can find information from WordPress.org here https://wordpress.org/support/article/editing-wp-config-php/